# CSS3 variable not working even though syntax is correct

Tags: html, css

The css file has already been linked and other styling is being applied on the html page. Declaring a variable that will store color:

```
:root {
  --accent-color: blue;
}
```

Trying to use the variable to colour the bottom border:

```
<nav
      style="background: whitesmoke !important;
      border-bottom: 2px solid var(--accent-color);"
      class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top"
></nav>
```

And yet the colour doesn't change. I tried creating a new folder and new files just to test variables and it worked there. I have a few cdns linked to the file in which I am trying to get it to work, all the 'get started' cdns from bootstrap which includes jquery, popper js and the bootstrap css and js files.

P.S. I pinpointed out why it isnt working though I do not understand the reason behind it. When I use Visual Studio live server to see the changes, the variable is interpreted, but when I am using XAMPP server and accessing website at localhost, the variable doesnt seem to make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

> The css file has already been linked and other styling is being
>   applied on the html page.

Nevertheless, you can move your inline styles from your markup to a CSS stylesheet.

**Working Example:**

```css
:root {
  --accent-color: blue;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--accent-color);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top"></nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't reference a variable inline like that. What you can do is declare the variable inline and use it in your stylesheet like this:

```
<div class="item" data-text="boop" style="--rotation:-45deg; --color: red"></div>
<div class="item" data-text="zap" style="--rotation:-20deg; --color: blue"></div>
<div class="item" data-text="pow" style="--rotation:20deg; --color: hotpink"></div>
<div class="item" data-text="ftang" style="--rotation:45deg; --color: goldenrod"></div>
```

css

```
.item:after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
  color: var(--color);
  content: attr(data-text) ;
}
```

**Source**: https://codepen.io/BPScott/pen/gRLXKJ

Comment: *You can't reference a variable inline like that* --> we can

Comment: Well, my bad then. I would love to see how.

Comment: simply run the OP code and you will see the blue border: https://jsfiddle.net/namjd2po/

Comment: The syntax is fine, the problem seems to lie with whether I use XAMPP or the VS live server extension. The XAMPP server doesn't seem to understand the variables in my stylesheet.